# Displaying prime numbers less than or equal to input in c++ using two functions

Tags: c++

I need to create a c++ program which displays all the prime numbers less than or equal to an inputted value. The catch is (and the part I can't seem to do) is that I have to use two functions to do so, and I cannot output the values within the same function that determines if they are prime or not. Below are two programs, the first is a program which does not work, this is as far as I got through trial and error after realizing that the second program does not meet the requirements. The second program works, but does not fulfill the requirements stated above. Thank you in advance, this has been driving me bonkers.

```
First:



 bool is_Prime(int);

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        int m, n;
        n = 2;
        cout << "Your input: ";
        cin >> m;
        cout << "The prime numbers less than or equal to " << m << " are:" << endl;

        while ( n <= m)
        {
            is_Prime(m);

            if (true) {
                cout << n << endl;
            }
            n++;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    bool is_Prime(int m) {
        for (int n = 1; n < m; n++) {
            bool prime = true;

            for (int x = 2; x*x <= m; x++) {
                if (m % x == 0) {
                 prime = false;
                }
            }

            if (prime = true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }


    Second: 


    bool is_Prime(int m);

    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        int m;

        cout << "Your input: ";
        cin >> m;

        cout << "The prime numbers less than or equal to " << m << " are:" << endl;
        is_Prime(m);

        return 0;
    }

bool is_Prime(int m) {
    for (int n = 1; n < m; n++) {
        bool prime = true;

        for (int x = 2; x*x <= n; x++) {
            if (n % x == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }

        if (prime)
            cout << n << " " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a) This is not C#. b) This is not C. Tags removed

Comment: What requirement is not fulfilled by the working code?

Comment: My mistake, I'll make note of the need to keep tags precise for future reference, thank you.

Comment: The working code outputs the values within the second function, nothing is supposed to be outputted in the second function, it is only supposed to return a bool value then that is supposed to be used to output a value (if true) in the main function. This is then supposed to repeat until all numbers less than or equal to the user input have been checked and outputted if prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that following function prints the numbers itself.

```
bool is_Prime(int m) {
    for (int n = 1; n < m; n++) {
        bool prime = true;

        for (int x = 2; x*x <= n; x++) {
            if (n % x == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }

        if (prime)
            cout << n << " " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Solution one:
Modify the function so that it only checks one given number if it is a prime, and in main, make a loop from 1 up to the max number, call is_prime for each numer, and print the number if the function returns true.

```
bool is_Prime(int p) {
    for (int x = 2; x*x <= p; x++) {
        if (p % x == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
...
//in main:
for(int p = 1; p < m; p++)
{
    if(is_prime(p))
        cout << p << endl;
}
```

Solution two (better):
Make another variable in the function, eg. a `std::vector<int> v;`, and instead of printing found primes, add them to the vector with `v.push_back(n);`. The return the whole vector (after all numbers are checked). In main, just print every number contained in the vector. This enables you to use better algorithms in the function (because one call checks all numbers), like sieve approaches, to make everything faster.

Comment: It said to avoid comments like "thanks", I'm not sure if this applies as well but, good tidings and good fortune to you sir/madam, may the odds be forever in your favor.

Comment: Your breakdown of how to solve the original problem rather than addressing the problems with the OP's attempt is good.

Comment: Actually, the first solution they showed was one I had attempted way previous to this, but couldn't figure out how to do. I was on the right track at one point believe it or not. The ugly monster (I'm thinking toxic avenger) of a program you see above is the result of several hours of incoherent thought processes and frustration. The second program is one that I'd written, then tried to change (in much the wrong way) when I realized it wasn't what I needed. So while your comments are correct, and somewhat helpful, the first program is really just me trying to fix the second in an incorrect way

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors in your second attempt (labeled as first).

```
is_Prime(m);
```

This is constantly checking the one number, not all of the numbers less than m, replace m with n.

```
if (true) {
```

This will always be executed. Either store the return value of is_Prime, or call it directly in the if statement.

if (prime = true)

This will set prime to true and then test prime. You want ==.

You don't return false at the end of is_Prime

```
for (int n = 1; n < m; n++) {
```

This isn't necessary in the is_Prime function as you have the while loop in the outside function.